# Comparing part of a filename from a text file to filenames from a directory (grep + awk)

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep, compare

This is not exactly the easiest one to explain in a title.

I have a file `inputfile.txt` that contains parts of filenames:

```
file1.abc
filed.def
fileq.lmn
```

This file is an input file that I need to use to find the full filenames of an actual directory. The ends of the filenames are different from case to case, but part of them is always the same.

I figured that I could grep text from the input file to the ls command in said directory (or the ls command to a simple text file), and then use awk to output my full desired result, but I'm having some trouble doing that.

`file1.abc` is read from the input file `inputfile.txt`
It's checked against the directory contents.
If the file exists, specific directories based on the filename are created.

(I'm also in a Busybox environment.. I don't have a lot at my disposal)

Something like this...

```
cat lscommandoutput.txt \
        | awk -F: '{print("mkdir" system("grep $0"); inputfile.txt}' \
        | /bin/sh
```

Thank you.

Edit: My apologies for not being clear on this.
The output should be the full filename of each line found in lscommandoutput.txt using the inputfile.txt to grep those specific lines.

If inputfile.txt contains:

```
file1.abc
filed.def
fileq.lmn
```

and lscommandoutput.txt contains:

```
file0.oba.ca-1.fil
file1.abc.de-1.fil
filed.def.com-2.fil
fileh.jkl.open-1.fil
fileq.lmn.he-2.fil
```

The extra lines that aren't contained in the inputfile.txt are ignored. The ones that are in the inputfile.txt have a directory created for them with the name that got grepped from lscommandoutput.txt.

```
/dir/dir2/file1.abc.de-1.fil/ <-- directory in which files can be placed in
/dir/dir2/filed.def.com-2.fil/
/dir/dir2/fileq.lmn.he-2.fil/
```

Hopefully that is a little bit clearer.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If the file `file1.abc` exists, what should happen? If it doesn't, what should happen?

Comment: You have this list of file-names as input to your program. But what is the output you want? I do not understand. Is it the path-name of a directory holding the file? Or the path-name of the file? In which directory is it to search?

Comment: does `find /startDir -type f | fgrep -f yourListFile` get you started in the right direction? Good luck.

Comment: @Raedwald and newfurniturey: I'm sorry. I added an edit that explains what I'm expecting as the output.

Comment: Okay. I believe that I've come up with a mildly more efficient (or usable) way of making this work.

By using `grep`, I can do half of the work.

`grep -f ./inputfile.txt ./lscommandoutput.txt > ./output.txt`

I'm able to match parts from the input to the directory and create a file that contains the full names of each of the input expressions.

My problem now is using the outputted file with the one file I want to put the folders. In other places, I comma-delimit my lines, and say that `/file/$1/folder/$2`. now I have only one part of the file, and need to put a specified file in that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you win a [useless use of `cat` award](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Secondly, you've explained this *really* badly. If you can't describe the problem clearly in plain English it's not surprising you are having trouble turning it into a script or set of commands.

`grep -f` is a good way to get the directory names, but I don't understand what you want to do with them afterwards.

> My problem now is using the outputted file with the one file I want to put the folders

Wut?  What does "the one file I want to put the folders" mean?  Where does the file come from? Is it the file named in `inputlist.txt`?  Does it go in the directory that it matched?

If you just want to create the directories you can do:

```
fgrep -f ./inputfile.txt ./lscommandoutput.txt | xargs mkdir
```

N.B. you probably want `fgrep` so that the input strings aren't treated as regular expressions and regex metacharacters such as `.` are ignored.

Comment: My apologies Jonathan. I didn't proofread my posts. I am sorry for coming across as I did (ignorant and stupid). My explanation was terrible. Thank you for the few points you made. I'm not exactly new to shell scripting, but I definitely need to brush up on certain concepts. I'll start by making less liberal use of the `cat` command. Your answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: It didn't sound ignorant or stupid (there are plenty of questions on SO that do, and this wasn't one of them!) it just wasn't at all clear what the goal was. That makes it hard for anyone to give a good answer, but maybe also prevents you turning the description of the problem in your head into a set of concrete steps that can be executed by a computer. The useless use of cat award is a humourous way of pointing out simpler ways to use the shell, it's mostly a bit of fun, but the point it makes is valid